# How to change spaces to underscore and make string case insensitive?

Tags: java, android, string, case-insensitive, replaceall

I have following question. In my app there is a listview. I get itemname from listview and transfer it to the webview as a string. How to ignore case of this string and change spaces to underscores?

For example: `String itemname = "First Topic"`. I transfer it to the next activity and want to ignore case and change space to underscore (I want to get `first_topic` in result).
I get "itemname" in webviewactivity and want to do what I've described for following code:

```
String filename = bundle.getString("itemname") + ".html";
```

Please, help.

Answer (score 132, accepted):

use `replaceAll` and `toLowerCase` methods like this:

`myString = myString.replaceAll(" ", "_").toLowerCase()`

Comment: Thanks, but I have no result. I use it in activity as   `String itemname = bundle.getString("itemname");
itemname.replaceAll(" ", "_").toLowerCase();` And then `String filename = itemname + ".html";` May be it's not right. Please, have a look.

Comment: u need to write it as itemname = itemname.replaceAll(" ", "_").toLowerCase();

Comment: @naini answered... these methods are not modifying the string they just return a new modified string so you should assign the new value.

Answer (score 41):

This works for me:

```
itemname = itemname.replaceAll("\\s+", "_").toLowerCase();
```

`replaceAll("\\s+", "_")` replaces consecutive whitespaces with a single underscore.

`"first  topic".replaceAll("\\s+", "_")` -> `first_topic`

`"first  topic".replaceAll(" ", "_")` -> `first__topic`

Comment: I think in most cases, your answer is better than the accepted one.

Comment: This answer covers more cases it should be the accepted one

Answer (score 7):

You can use the replaceAll & toLowerCase methods but keep in mind that they don't change the string (they just return a modified string) so you need to assign the back to the variable, eg.

```
String itemname = bundle.getString("itemname"); 
itemname = itemname.replaceAll(" ", "_").toLowerCase(); 
String filename = itemname + ".html";
```

Comment: Doh, question was answered as a comment to previous answer whilst I typed (and I guess I should have posted as a comment - new to StackOverflow)